Cannot resolve symbol SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory after upgrading spring-boot version from 2.x to 3.x
As I am trying to upgrade the version of spring-boot from 2.6.8 to 3.1.6 in my application, I am encountering some issues. I have resolved almost all of them by ugrading spring-cloud-aws version and other dependent libraries as well. However there is this one issue where I am stuck.
So in my application, as we are consuming the messages from a queue, we are using SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory to configure the following:
factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor); // this sets concurrency limit in another method
        factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);   // long polling enabled
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

As I am upgrading, SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory gets unresolvable. The compiler states "Cannot resolve symbol SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory". I know this has either been renamed or there must be some alternate way of achieving this. However I am stuck and not able to figure this out.
Can someone share if they have done this or know the solution to this?
Tried searching for it and got this not very useful article: Which Spring Cloud AWS version should be used with Spring Boot 3?
